# PHP: set_time_limit() seems to have no effect whatsoever

Tags: php, timeout

I'm trying to use PHP's set_time_limit() in a normal PHP apache script (not CLI) to limit its max running time. It's not doing anything with system calls or anything similar, we're not using safe mode (we're the owners but not the admins of the server). This is PHP 5.2.4 on Linux (Ubuntu).

Simple test case:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1);
set_time_limit(1);
$i=0;
while ($i++<100000000000) {} // or anything other arbitrary that takes time
die('Done');
```

**Expected result**: something relating to the script execution time being exceeded

**Actual result**: Done is printed.

Am I doing something obvious wrong? <sub>(By the way, yes, the script really needs to and can run for too long and need to be aborted, it's unfortunately not something that can be avoided. That is not the point here.)</sub>

Comment: @StrikerNL Mark Baker (below) is right. On Windows you will get a max execution time exceeded error (cos sleep() time counts in Windows), but not in Linux.

Comment: Yes, that's true. See revised version please. Sorry about that.

Comment: @StrikerNL maybe your server is too powerful. How long does the script take? Try debugging with microtime() at the top an bottom of it.

Comment: Adding zeroes does not really seem to help. I think I'm running into some kind of bug, on my local dev server all works as expected. Maybe I need to look into getting PHP upgraded to a more recent version, or alternatively implementing something using register_tick_function() or something similar.

Comment: @StrikerNL See my updated answer, it may be the bug you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, perhaps, however, I am running 5.2.4, so that bugfix should be included. Perhaps something similar?

Comment: Check your disable_functions flag in php.ini. What does it read?

Comment: Cannot seem to get this formatted properly, but both empty: $ cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep disable_
disable_functions =
disable_classes =

Comment: Okay its not disabled... check out my answer below: echo phpinfo() right after your ini set and see if the local value has changed. Try that.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the manual:

> **Note:**
>
> The set_time_limit() function and the
>   configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the
>   execution time of the script itself.
>   Any time spent on activity that
>   happens outside the execution of the
>   script such as system calls using
>   system(), stream operations, database
>   queries, etc. is not included when
>   determining the maximum time that the
>   script has been running. This is not
>   true on Windows where the measured
>   time is real.

sleep() is among those functions that do not affect the running time of the script

see MPHH's comment on the sleep() page of the manual

> Note: The set_time_limit() function
>   and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the
>   execution time of the script itself.
>   Any time spent on activity that
>   happens outside the execution of the
>   script such as system calls using
>   system(), the sleep() function,
>   database queries, etc. is not included
>   when determining the maximum time that
>   the script has been running.

Comment: Yes, that's true. See revised version please. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

On some systems ini_set and similar functions are disabled for security and resource sharing reasons. Check with your administrator to see if such restrictions are in place.

Comment: No, I think all functions are enabled and there should be no restrictions. We own the server, but do not admin it.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you own the server, it would be advisable to doublecheck. A good sysadmin will lock the box as tight as possible first and then ease the security as the need arises.

Answer (score 2):

Both max_execution_time(...) and ini_set('max_execution_time',...) won't count the time cost of sleep(),file_get_contents(),shell_exec(),mysql_query() etc, so i build the following function my_background_exec() to run a static method on the background/detached process and when time is out, kill it automatically:

my_exec.php:

```
<?php
function my_background_exec($function_name, $params, $str_requires, $timeout=600)
         {$map=array('"'=>'\"', '$'=>'\$', '`'=>'\`', '\\'=>'\\\\', '!'=>'\!');
          $str_requires=strtr($str_requires, $map);
          $path_run=dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
          $my_target_exec="/usr/bin/php -r \"chdir('{$path_run}');{$str_requires}\\\$params=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'),true);call_user_func_array('{$function_name}', \\\$params);\"";
          $my_target_exec=strtr(strtr($my_target_exec, $map), $map);
          $my_background_exec="(/usr/bin/php -r \"chdir('{$path_run}');{$str_requires}my_timeout_exec(\\\"{$my_target_exec}\\\", file_get_contents('php://stdin'), {$timeout});\" <&3 &) 3<&0";//php by default use "sh", and "sh" don't support "<&0"
          my_timeout_exec($my_background_exec, json_encode($params), 2);
         }

function my_timeout_exec($cmd, $stdin='', $timeout)
         {$start=time();
          $stdout='';
          $stderr='';
          //file_put_contents('debug.txt', time().':cmd:'.$cmd."\n", FILE_APPEND);
          //file_put_contents('debug.txt', time().':stdin:'.$stdin."\n", FILE_APPEND);

          $process=proc_open($cmd, [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']], $pipes);
          if (!is_resource($process))
             {return array('return'=>'1', 'stdout'=>$stdout, 'stderr'=>$stderr);
             }
          $status=proc_get_status($process);
          posix_setpgid($status['pid'], $status['pid']);    //seperate pgid(process group id) from parent's pgid

          stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], 0);
          stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
          stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);
          fwrite($pipes[0], $stdin);
          fclose($pipes[0]);

          while (1)
                {$stdout.=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
                 $stderr.=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

                 if (time()-$start>$timeout)
                    {//proc_terminate($process, 9);    //only terminate subprocess, won't terminate sub-subprocess
                     posix_kill(-$status['pid'], 9);    //sends SIGKILL to all processes inside group(negative means GPID, all subprocesses share the top process group, except nested my_timeout_exec)
                     //file_put_contents('debug.txt', time().":kill group {$status['pid']}\n", FILE_APPEND);
                     return array('return'=>'1', 'stdout'=>$stdout, 'stderr'=>$stderr);
                    }

                 $status=proc_get_status($process);
                 //file_put_contents('debug.txt', time().':status:'.var_export($status, true)."\n";
                 if (!$status['running'])
                    {fclose($pipes[1]);
                     fclose($pipes[2]);
                     proc_close($process);
                     return $status['exitcode'];
                    }

                 usleep(100000); 
                }
         }
?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
my_background_exec('A::jack', array('hello ', 'jack'), 'require "my_exec.php";require "a_class.php";', 8);
?>
```

a_class.php:

```
<?php
class A
{
    static function jack($a, $b)
           {sleep(4);
            file_put_contents('debug.txt', time().":A::jack:".$a.' '.$b."\n", FILE_APPEND);
            sleep(15);
           }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the function sleep is ignored by the time limit, it will stop counting time when sleep is activated and start counting again when it's deactivated.

Comment: Yes, that's true. See revised version please.

Comment: Sorry, but i tried running your revised script, and i don't see 'Done' get printed, i can't replicate the error. I'll have to pass on this one, sorry. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try having your script actually do something, sleep time isn't counted towards execution time since while the script is sleeping it's not executing.

**EDIT :** Check out this bugreport http://bugs.php.net/37306 The last comment is that it was fixed in "CVS HEAD, PHP_5_2 and PHP_5_1." so maybe your PHP version has this bug. Maybe you can you try changing the `max_input_time`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. See revised version please. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your ini_set works by checking the disable_functions flag in php.ini. If it is not disabled, echo phpinfo() immediately after your ini_set('max_execution_time', 1); above. If the value is changed under the local column, then you know ini_set works. Else, your script has not set any maximum execution time, then.

Comment: Yes, according to phpinfo() it has changed. Yet it seems not to respect it.